# An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later

Tags: uploads

I'm getting an error with creating a new campaign for the new user for uploading an image.

An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.

It works if I submit campaign without adding a new image. Image upload works on the new campaign after creating the first campaign without any image. It is a bit confusing.

I'm using wp-crowdfunding plugin and crowdfunding theme. Please help if you what is missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are working on local wordpress install in unix like systems make sure your uploads directory is writable. Use this command to check :( ls -lah)
then : (sudo chmod -R 755 uploads)

Please make sure if your new user have necessary privileges to make those changes to your wordpress site.
when creating a new user make sure you are doing it properly. It is very important you understand this for security reasons.
for further detail I would like you to explore further on your own: https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities
Hope it helps
Good Luck!!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I checked the permission and it has.

I'm also using woo commerce plugin and it is causing issues. Here is what I did and it worked

- created a new user
- login through woo commerce form
- opened wp-crowdfunding dasboard
- upload image on the profile
-- it worked without any error

It is not a solution as something is breaking b/w woocommerce and wp-crowdfunging login

Thanks.